# Rails: limit enum column for already submitted values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, enums, model, associations

In my rails app I have 2 models: post and post_translations.

```
class PostTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  LANGUAGES = %w( en fr es de it )
  validates_inclusion_of :language, :in => LANGUAGES

end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_translations

end
```

I want to prevent the same language translation from being submitted twice, so I want to limit the enums to the values not listed in the language column of a particular post_id.
I don't know if I should do this in model, controller or helper.
Which is the best practice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an attribute on the class instead of defining it on an instance.

```
class PostTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
  @@languages = %w( en fr es de it )
  cattr_reader :languages

  belongs_to :post

  validates :language, :inclusion => { :in => @@languages },
    :uniqueness => { :scope => :post_id }
end
```

Now to fulfill your requirement of showing only the languages without translations, define a method on Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_translations

  def untranslated
    PostTranslation.languages - post_translations.map(&:language)
  end
end
```

Then you can build a select menu by getting a post (`@post = Post.find(params[:id]`) and populating the collection from `@post.untranslated`.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly valid to keep this in the model. Models should hold primary responsibility for ensuring that the data entered into them is correct.

For your particular case, you can use the `:uniqueness` validator with a scope passed to it. Basically your validation will ensure that languages are unique *in the context of a particular post*

The following should work:

```
validates :language, :inclusion => { :in => LANGUAGES },
                     :uniqueness => { :scope => :post_id }
```

If you prefer the Rails 2 style syntax, you can use:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :language, :scope => :post_id
```

Comment: ok, this will prevent the record from been saved, but in my selection list I still can choose all the languages: how can I hide the languages already submitted?

Comment: I think this needs a column name, so `:scope => :post_id`

Comment: notme, I think you could probably do something in a helper like `LANGUAGES - @post.post_translations.all.map { |pt| pt.language }`.